# i can not identify the mistake in my code

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, char

// i dont know where is the problem here

package javaapplication3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1,num2;
    String input;
    input= new String();
    char again;
    while (again =='y' || again =='Y')
    {
        System.out.print("enter a number:");
        num1=keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("enter another number:");
        num2=keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("their sum is "+ (num1 + num2));
        System.out.println("do you want to do this again?");
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't assigned any value to `again` which you should do.

Comment: `char again;` will never be `'y'` or `'n'`

Comment: Exactly what problem is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `again` to some value otherwise it will give compilation error.

And also, at the end of while loop, you need to read data from scanner object and assign the value to `again` variable. Check your modified Java code,

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int num1, num2;
String input;
input = new String();
char again = 'y'; // You need to initialize it to y or Y so it can enter into while loop
while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y') {
    System.out.print("enter a number:");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("enter another number:");
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("their sum is " + (num1 + num2));
    System.out.println("do you want to do this again?");
    again = keyboard.next().charAt(0); // You need to take the input from user and assign it to again variable which will get checked in while loop condition
}
System.out.println("Program ends");
```

**Edit: A `do while` loop should be preferable here**

Check this code having `do while` loop where you don't need to worry about initializing `again` variable.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int num1, num2;
char again;
do { // the loop first executes without checking any condition and you don't need to worry about initializing "again" variable
    System.out.print("enter a number:");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("enter another number:");
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("their sum is " + (num1 + num2));
    System.out.println("do you want to do this again?");
    again = keyboard.next().charAt(0); // here "again" variable is initialized and assigned the value anyway
} while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y'); // checks the condition and accordingly executes the while loop or quits
keyboard.close();
System.out.println("Program ends");
```

Comment: hi ,,thank you for your answer, but i still have a question 
u asked me to set a value for the variable again , how can i give the value 'y' to the variable again and not 'Y' since in the code it says 'y' or 'Y' .....wht am trying to say is that dont u think that the variable again can take both of them but in a different times ???

Comment: @aminhadi: Not sure if I could get your question, but you can initialize the value of `again` to either `y` or `Y` because your while loop accepts both. Similarly, when it asks you to enter again, you can type `y` or `Y` and in both case it will work. Let me know if you have any other query. Also, I would suggest the usage of `do while` loop that will be more appropriate for your case. A [do while loop](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/do-while-loop-in-java-with-example/) starts first by executing the loop and then checks the condition whether it should again execute the loop or not.

Comment: @aminhadi: I've updated my answer with a `do while` loop codes which might suit you better. Please have a look and let me know in case you have any queries.